# After i added throws ParseException, the parse excception still occured, why?

Tags: java, date, time, days, parseexception

The question is to calculate the days between two dates. Here's my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd)");
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    String date1=input.nextLine();
    String date2=input.nextLine();
    Date d1 =sdf.parse(date1);
    Date d2= sdf.parse(date2);
    if(d1.getTime()>d2.getTime()) {
        System.out.println(d2.getTime()-d1.getTime()/(24*60*60*1000));
    }
    else
        System.out.println(d1.getTime()-d2.getTime()/(24*60*60*1000));
```

and output is

```
2010/05/29
2010/01/01
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2010/05/29"
        at java.base/java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:396)
        at HW10_09156136_1092.HW10_Ex01.main(HW10_Ex01.java:15)
```

Comment: Because adding the throws clause to a method does not prevent that exception from being thrown. Quite the opposite. It just marks that method as possibly throwing that exception so that callers can handle it in a try-catch-block if they want to. But as the main method is the entry point there is no special handling.

Comment: The solution to your problem is not to try to handle the exception in any way. Instead you need to look at why the exception happens and modify your code so that it doesn't get thrown. In your case you are trying to parse a date where year, month and day are separated by `/`, but in your dateformat you are using a format where you use `-`.

Comment: (1) Don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). (2) Don’t do your own time math. Yours is also incorrect. Leave date and time math to the library methods. (3) When entering you own code into a method, remove the comment `// TODO Auto-generated method stub`.

Answer (score 2):

You have used `m` [Minute in hour] at the place of `M` [Month in year].

Your input has `/` as the separator whereas you have specified `-` for it in the parser. The input should match the pattern specified with the parser.

Apart from this, the `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

### Demo using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateStart = "2021-06-09";
        String strDateEnd = "2021-06-12";
        LocalDate dateStart = LocalDate.parse(strDateStart);
        LocalDate dateEnd = LocalDate.parse(strDateEnd);
        long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(dateStart, dateEnd);
        System.out.println(days);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
3
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/ElkRUZ)

The modern Date-Time API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and does not require using a `DateTimeFormatter` object explicitly as long as the Date-Time string conforms to the ISO 8601 standards.

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

### Using the legacy API:

Avoid performing calculations yourself if there already exists an API for the same e.g. the following code uses [`Math#abs`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs-long-) and [`TimeUnit#convert`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#convert(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) to avoid error-prone if-else and calculations.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String strDateStart = "2021-06-09";
        String strDateEnd = "2021-06-12";
        
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date dateStart = sdf.parse(strDateStart);
        Date dateEnd = sdf.parse(strDateEnd);
        
        long millisInOneDay = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
        long days = Math.abs((dateEnd.getTime() - dateStart.getTime()) / millisInOneDay);
        
        System.out.println(days);
    }
}
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/tdadw4)

> After i added throws ParseException, the parse excception still
> occured, why?

Adding the `throws` clause to a method forces the caller of the method to either handle the exception using try-catch or rethrow it. It is not a way to prevent the exception from being thrown. Learn more about it from [this excellent tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html) from Oracle.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>